# Should project that will always use MySQL use PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have created a project which uses a MySQL-database in a very basic way. This means I only use SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. No joins, no table creation. Most queries are SELECTs and most of the time I only select some rows of one record.

I'm also quite sure that this project will always use MySQL.

Now I've heard about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and some people seem to think that it's in general a good idea to use it. According to php.net "PDO provides [only] a data-access abstraction layer".

Is there any reason why a project which will always use MySQL should use PDO? Any reason why it might be a bad idea to use PDO in such a project?

Comment: Even with PDO, you usually can't avoid using database specific things in the background. PDO doesn't abstract the actual queries, only the method of connecting to and communicating with the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a good idea, if only for prepared statements and bound parameters.

PDO supports different database drivers but does not provide database abstraction, it just provides a consistent interface to accessing data. There is really no drawback in using it, and `mysql_*` functions should just be dropped.

Comment: Prepared statements and bound parameters are fully available in the mysqli extension. The issue with people using the mysql extension is that they don't bother looking for how to do things properly, not that the tool aren't readily available (I completely support using PDO even if only mysql will be used though).

Comment: `mysqli` doesn't have named parameters though, which is kind of silly

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Why sould mysql_* functions be dropped?

Comment: Because their utility is very limited: they just provide basic access, are tied to mysql and force you to escape queries (which a lot of PHP programmers fail to do properly or completely ignore) since they don't provide prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you should not use it.

You can also be totally safe not using it, just remember to use the modern extension mysqli and not mysql, and use parameterized queries instead of the utter mess that is string concatenation and mysql_real_escape_string().

The reason why you should be using PDO, however, is that it will teach you how to use an interface database that will give you the generic knowledge to work on any other database in your future projects. In other words, it will teach you to differentiate "ask some data from the database" from "how exactly does this particular database need to be called".
Again, use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no joins why are you using a relational database in the first place? You just need a key/value store.

I usually don't use pdo for MySQL specific projects.

Comment: I know that I only need a key/value store. But my provider only allows me to use MySQL databases. So if you know an easier/faster PHP-only way to store many tiny data bits over several years and to access them fast please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PDO is mostly used for object oriented programming. It is also a lot safer and faster than MySQL. Since you are accessing data for CRUD (create,read, update,delete) it is actually more efficient than MySQL.

Only problem I see is to install the PDO driver, but it is installed on most servers now.

So, if you're going to use OOP, the you must use PDO.